# If $z^n + z^{-n} = 2\cos(n\theta)$, prove $5z^4 - z^3 - 6z^2 - z + 5 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $z^n + z^{-n} = 2\cos(n\theta)$, show that $$5z^4 - z^3 - 6z^2 - z + 5 = 0 \Longrightarrow 10\cos^2\theta-\cos \theta -8=0.$$

I've substituting 2, 3 and 4 for $n$ and then playing with  the answers i got but i didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Manipulate the expression to get something like $z^n + z^{-n}$. E.G. $z^2 + 1 = 0 \implies z(z+z^{-1}) = 0$.

Comment: Divide the equation by $z^2$ assuming $z\neq0$.

Comment: hi so I proved that expression is equal to 10cos square..... but i still dont know how ti prove that it is equal to zero